# Python program fails to execute 50% of the time

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I’m currently in the process of porting software from Python 2.7 to Python 3.7, and I’m seeing something that I have no idea how to address. When I type “python –m project.main” to run the software, about 50% of the time nothing happens and a fresh command prompt line prints after a few seconds with no error message or traceback whatsoever. The other half of the time, the program runs perfectly. There doesn’t appear to be any discernable pattern of success vs failure

To try and gather further information, I tried out Python 3’s “faulthandler” package, but most of the time I still see no error message. Once in a while, it does print a cryptic “Windows fatal exception: access violation” with accompanying traceback (but no further details), but again there seems to be no pattern as to when the message prints among the failed runs.

As background, the software builds a QApplication (PyQt5), and we’re running on Windows 10 with Anacdona 3.7. As I mentioned, we recently upgraded from Python 2.7, and never saw anything like this. Most of the migration has gone relatively smoothly – like I said, when the program does run, it works fine.

Has anyone else encountered anything like this? The apparent randomness of the failures is driving me crazy.

Comment: Have you tried doing the same thing with a minimal project containing nothing but a shell QApplication and a QMainWindow? Run it a few times. This will immediately give you a hint as to whether it's your application or your installation at fault.

Comment: @replete Good idea. A skeletal QApplication (I copied the sample from [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/dialog.html)) seems to run reliably, so it looks like it's related to the code itself.